# Simple Form Checkboxes - applying styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, rails-i18n, simple-form-for

I have two models in many-to-many relationship.

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features
end
```

and

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rentals
end
```

In my `rentals/1/new` form I have a field with checkbox collection where user can add features to the rental.
This field works correctly, but the default bootstrap styling is not applied. Basically, `wrapper: :vertical_collection_inline` doesn't do anything here. It's now one sad vertical checkbox collection.
How can I add styling to this field? I did read https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#the-wrappers-api but can't seem to find the answer...I need it to be this way because I need to be able to translate every feature name.

```
<%= f.input :feature_ids, as: :check_boxes do %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :feature_ids, Feature.order(:name), :id, :name, wrapper: :vertical_collection_inline  do |b|
   b.label { b.check_box + " " + t("#{b.text}") }
   end %>
<% end %>
```

This other solution works and looks good (has the Bootstrap styling applied) but I can't figure out how to translate the feature names on it..

```
<%= f.input :feature_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Feature.all, wrapper: :vertical_collection_inline %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I only needed to post on here in order to find the answer myself! This works both for style and translation:

```
<%= f.input :feature_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Feature.all.map {|f| [t("#{f.name}"),f.id]}, wrapper: :vertical_collection_inline %>
```